# Problema with azure sdk and jackson version

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have an java application where I'm trying to comunicate with azure key vault to create keys.
This is my code:

```
    public void generateProductAuthKeyPair(Long channelId) {
        try {
            KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();

            String keyName = "UseAuthKeyChannel" + channelId.toString();
            CreateEcKeyOptions keyOptions = new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName);
            keyOptions.setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256);

            KeyVaultKey key = keyClient.createEcKey(keyOptions);

            Channel channel = channelRepository.getChannelById(channelId);
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.cittamobi.abr</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsm</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>ABT Hsm Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-keys</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.621</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.cittamobi.abt</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.50</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zenvia</groupId>
            <artifactId>zenvia-api-sdk-client-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.68.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.techgnious</groupId>
            <artifactId>IVCompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>hml</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>hml</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>hml-us</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>hml-us</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod-prodata</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod-prodata</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I keep getting error:

2024-01-11 16:47:44.391  INFO 21492 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.a.c.i.jackson.JacksonVersion           : Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.10.2, jackson-core=2.10.2, jackson-databind=2.10.2, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.10.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.10.2, azure-core=1.25.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot

I've already tried lots of versions in pom, but it seems to keep conflicting between themselves.
First time I'm trying to implement azure functions, so I'm a little confused.

Can someone help?

Comment: Those Spring and Jackson dependencies are almost four years old, but the Azure dependency is les than a month old.  Can you update Spring to latest 2.x, or even better 3.x?  Also, a specific Jackson version should not need to be specified, since that Spring parent will define the compatible version.

Comment: you have the spring boot parent that is fine for handling the version of the spring libs but you do miss the bom for azure. You should have both spring and azure bom for correctly handle dependencies versions https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Spring-Versions-Mapping

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Java application where I'm trying to communicate with Azure Key Vault to create keys.

The above error occurred due to the usage of a downgraded version. I agree with Andrew S's comment. please update Spring to the latest version for compatibility with the code.

Here is my sample code to create keys in Azure Key Vault using Java code.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateProductAuthKeyPair(123L);
    }

    public static void generateProductAuthKeyPair(Long channelId) {
        try {
            KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();

            String keyName = "UseAuthKeyChannel" + channelId.toString();
            CreateEcKeyOptions keyOptions = new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName);
            keyOptions.setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256);

            KeyVaultKey key = keyClient.createEcKey(keyOptions);

            System.out.println("Created key: " + key.getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Created key: UseAuthKeyChannel123
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Key Vault Key client library for Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-keys-readme?view=azure-java-stable#create-a-key)

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the version problem, but my keyClient keeps being created with error. I've published a question with more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806826/problem-when-creating-keyclient-with-azure-sdk-for-java
Could you help?

Comment: If you could share the versions you used in your example that works well, it would help me a lot

Comment: I used same dependency version. Try to exclude the `azure-core` dependency from Pom.xml.

Comment: same problem without azure-core dependency. my keyClient is created with error inside:
Method threw 'com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.MissingRequiredAnnotationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.sun.proxy.$Proxy264.toString()

Comment: @LucasPenna `CreateEcKeyOptions keyOptions = new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName);
            keyOptions.setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256);

            KeyVaultKey ecKey = keyClient.createEcKey(new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName)
                    .setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256)
                    .setExpiresOn(OffsetDateTime.now().plusYears(1)));
            System.out.printf("Key created with name \"%s\" and id %s%n", ecKey.getName(), ecKey.getId());` you are trying two times key option please use of my code to create keyoption one time.

Comment: Also, exclude `com.sun` in dependency.

Comment: Did the above solution is worked?

Comment: I've tried your code and I also removed con.sun in dependencies, but the problem is inside keyClient. When I evaluate my keyClient object there is a problem inside it's service.
I posted details in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806826/problem-when-creating-keyclient-with-azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: Could you tell me what version of spring you used?

Comment: I'm using Maven by refering this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-java?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: And what's your spring version?
I put the exactly same versions of the link you sent, and still does not work

Comment: I'm not using here spring using Maven I have created the key.