# Problem when creating KeyClient with Azure SDK for Java

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-sdk-for-java

I'm trying to create a KeyClient object in my code so I can create keys in azure key vault.
But my object keeps getting error on service and I could not solve it until now.
This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void generateProductAuthKeyPair(Long channelId) {
        try {
            KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();

            String keyName = "UseAuthKeyChannel" + channelId.toString();
            CreateEcKeyOptions keyOptions = new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName);
            keyOptions.setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256);

            KeyVaultKey ecKey = keyClient.createEcKey(new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName)
                    .setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256)
                    .setExpiresOn(OffsetDateTime.now().plusYears(1)));
            System.out.printf("Key created with name \"%s\" and id %s%n", ecKey.getName(), ecKey.getId());

            Channel channel = channelRepository.getChannelById(channelId);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Everytime I create the keyClient, it's created with an error inside service, as you can see in the image:

[image]

It seems to be missing anotations inside service, but it is an internal class.
I'm using latest versions of azure sdk.
Here follow my dependencies inside pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-keys</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.45.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.621</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.cittamobi.abt</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.50</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zenvia</groupId>
            <artifactId>zenvia-api-sdk-client-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.68.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.techgnious</groupId>
            <artifactId>IVCompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The keyClient is created but I can't perform any functions with it, cause the service throws exception.
Does someone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code and was able to create a key in the Azure Key Vault.

**Code :**

***KeyVaultService.java :***

```java
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.KeyClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.KeyClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.models.CreateEcKeyOptions;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.models.KeyCurveName;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.models.KeyVaultKey;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Service
public class KeyVaultService {

    private static final String keyVaultUrl = "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/";

    public void generateProductAuthKeyPair(Long channelId) {
        try {
            KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClientBuilder()
                    .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                    .buildClient();

            String keyName = "<key_name>" + channelId.toString();
            CreateEcKeyOptions keyOptions = new CreateEcKeyOptions(keyName)
                    .setCurveName(KeyCurveName.P_256)
                    .setExpiresOn(OffsetDateTime.now().plusYears(1));

            KeyVaultKey ecKey = keyClient.createEcKey(keyOptions);
            System.out.printf("Key created with name \"%s\" and id %s%n", ecKey.getName(), ecKey.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***KeyController.java :***

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/keys")
public class KeyController {

    private final KeyVaultService keyVaultService;

    @Autowired
    public KeyController(KeyVaultService keyVaultService) {
        this.keyVaultService = keyVaultService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/generate")
    public String generateProductAuthKeyPair() {
        keyVaultService.generateProductAuthKeyPair(123L);
        return "Key generation initiated. Check logs for details.";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml :**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-keys</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.45.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Output :**

The code ran successfully and created a key in Azure Key Vault.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/keys/generate
```

[image]

```
Key created with name "kamalikey123" and id
https://kamxvault.vault.azure.net/keys/kamalikey1123/9fd9fa14xxxxxxx
```

[image]

**Azure Portal :**

The key was successfully created in Azure Key Vault, as shown below.

[image]